# MongoDB update sub document issue

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I'm having Mongo structure like this,

```
"campaigns":[{
    "summary" : 
      [ { 
       "postcode" : [ { 
                       "id" : "71",
                       "name" : "Recall 1",
                        "qty" : 3, 
                       "history" : 
                            [ { "timestamp" : "2014-12-16 11:15:32",
                               { "timestamp":  "2014-12-16 11:15:53"
                            } ] 
                       } ] 
     },
     {
     "postcode" :
            [ {     
                "id" : "72", 
                "name" : "Recall 2", 
                "qty" : 1,
                "history" : [ { "timestamp" : "2014-12-16 11:15:53" } ] 
           } ] 
  }]
```

I'm trying to i) increment qty of postcode.id : 72 ii) insert another timestamp for that same postcode id 72.

My code:

```
    $collection->update(array("campaigns.task.id" => $b,"_id"=> new MongoId($objectid),"campaigns.0.summary.0.postcode.0.id" => $a), array('$inc' =>  array('campaigns.0.summary.0.postcode.0.qty' => 1)));
    $collection->update(array("campaigns.task.id" => $b,"_id"=>new MongoId($objectid),"campaigns.0.summary.0.postcode.0.id" => $a),
 array('$addToSet' =>  array('campaigns.0.summary.0.postcode.0.history' => array("timestamp"=>$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))));
```

but postcode.id = 72 not gets updated, i'm confused with this nested subdocument can anyone suggest me the solution ?

Comment: Your document is malformed. For example, what is going on in the first object in the history array in `"postcode.id" : 72`? Can you post a complete, well-formed MongoDB document? Then I will formulate queries to modify what you want, if possible.